# When should I use starter web and starter webflux dependency in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, spring-webflux, crud

starter web and starter  webflux dependency in Spring Boot. I am fall in dilemma. Please let me know what is the differences both of these. When, how, where should I used it? how to CRUD using both, starter web and starter  webflux dependency? I am very new in this platform.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I cannot understand it. so how to do this?

Comment: you should start using them when you start needing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that Spring Web MVC (spring-boot-starter-web) uses a synchronous programming model and Spring WebFlux (spring-boot-starter-webflux) uses an asynchronous (reactive) model.

The synchronous model uses a Java thread for each request and all method calls run synchronously in this thread returning the objects directly.

The asynchronous model uses reactive programming and each method call in a single request may be handled in different threads. The methods you write have to be non-blocking and return instances `Mono` or `Flux`.

I would recommend to start with Web MVC and the synchronous model as it is a lot easier to code and debug.

[Spring MVC Async vs Spring WebFlux](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-async-vs-webflux) gives a more detailed comparison.

Comment: `@derkoe`    If I want to create a CRUD through WebFlux ( Mono & Flux )   it will works same as Web MVC? Like, all methods, Collections, ArrayLists and so on?

Comment: It works quite the same - you'll only have to wrap all results in Mono or Flux. To see the difference in a real app look at https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-reactive vs. https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic